# List installed windows Xbox game locations

Tags: windows, powershell, appx

I want to be able to list the currently installed windows xbox store apps, and at least what hard drive they are installed to, though the installed size would also be helpful.

As an example, I've installed [Astroneer](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/games/store/astroneer/9NBLGGH43KZB) to my `D:\` drive. I can see the installation location:

```
# Astroneer folder
D:\WindowsApps\SystemEraSoftworks.29415440E1269_1.21.128.0_x64__ftk5pbg2rayv2\

# Other game package types can install to an MSIXVC file, e.g.
D:\WindowsApps\MSIXVC\130F32F8-4ABB-49E2-9200-3C4FCE2271C8
```

I can see the appx package, but its `InstallLocation` points to a junction point within the default appx volume instead:

```
Get-AppxPackage -Name "SystemEraSoftworks*"

Name              : SystemEraSoftworks.29415440E1269
Publisher         : CN=115C80E5-07B4-4D9C-8912-5562D4A1828D
Architecture      : X64
ResourceId        :
Version           : 1.21.128.0
PackageFullName   : SystemEraSoftworks.29415440E1269_1.21.128.0_x64__ftk5pbg2rayv2
InstallLocation   : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\SystemEraSoftworks.29415440E1269_1.21.128.0_x64__ftk5pbg2rayv2
```

The appx manifest doesn't contain any information about which drive the app is installed on.

I searched through the registry a bit, but only found references to the `C:\` path, or using relative paths like:

```
Get-ItemProperty 'hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppModel\StateRepository\Cache\Activation\Data\18a' -Name 'Executable'

Executable   : Astro\Binaries\UWP64\Astro-UWP64-Shipping.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

I found I could parse the junction points with `Get-Item` and check the install folders for xbox config files:

```
# List all windows store packages. May want to include -AllUsers?
Get-AppxPackage | 
  # Filter out unwanted packages
  Where {!$_.IsFramework -and !$_.NonRemovable -and $_.SignatureKind -eq 'Store'} |
  Select Name, @{l='InstallLocation';e={
    # Return the junction target instead of the local install folder
    If ((Get-Item $_.InstallLocation).LinkType -eq 'Junction') {
      (Get-Item $_.InstallLocation).Target
    }
    Else { $_.InstallLocation }
  }} |
  # Filter to Xbox games
  Where { Test-Path "$($_.InstallLocation)\MicrosoftGame.config" }


# Outputs:
Name                                               InstallLocation                                                                                           
----                                               ---------------                                                                                           
KalypsoMediaGroup.Tropico6Win                      C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\KalypsoMediaGroup.Tropico6Win_15.3.553.0_x64__e60j8nnj33ga6                  
WarnerBros.Interactive.e172091a-6630-4ff3-959f-830 F:\WindowsApps\WarnerBros.Interactive.e172091a-6630-4ff3-959f-830_1.279.9438.0_x64__ktmk1xygcecda         
SystemEraSoftworks.29415440E1269                   D:\WindowsApps\SystemEraSoftworks.29415440E1269_1.21.128.0_x64__ftk5pbg2rayv2
```

I'm not sure if I can find the package installation sizes anywhere though, although they are listed in the xbox app.